# throws vs Java Bytecode

Tags: java, exception, bytecode

The `throws` list of a method obviously plays a role during compilation. Does it however have any impact whatsoever during runtime?

For instance, if I have a method without a `throws` list and use dark bytecode magic to summon and throw an `IncrediblyCheckedException`, would it throw it without question or would the runtime validator notice this and throw an error or something instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has no effect on the runtime whatsoever. Case in point:

```
Thread.currentThread.stop(new Exception());
```

can be written *anywhere* and the line of code will throw the exception.

The above will throw the exception from native code, but here's another trick with a plain Java `throw`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CurrentClass.<RuntimeException>sneakyThrow(new Exception());
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <E extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(Throwable t) throws E { 
  throw (E)t; 
}
```

Comment: In fact, I've seen something similar to that sneakyThrow in production applications. You know a language feature is bad when nearly everything has code specifically to work around it.

Comment: You could have been looking at my work---I copypasted that from my production code :-)

Comment: The one I was thinking of was called throwAsUnchecked.

Comment: I didn't mean it that literally :-)

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().stop(new Exception());` does not work in Java 8 anymore. I think the main reason for using “sneaky throw” in production code was because it wasn’t possible to re-throw a `Throwable` easily before Java 7. Further, it may make sense in the context of `InvocationTargetException` and similar when you know that the reflectively called method throws the right exceptions only. But that’s rather special so I wouldn’t accuse the Java language for that.

Comment: @holger We use sneaky throw to throw checked exceptions without them actually being checked. I don't see how that's become easier in Java 7.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: I said *re-throwing* has become easier. Catching `Throwable` and re-thowing it assuming that a legal exception stays a legal exception is now possible in Java7. But, of course, perverting the concept of checked exceptions in general has not made easier. But I doubt that this is the main goal of most Java developers.

Comment: @Holger There is no essential difference between rethrowing and throwing. The only use of `sneakyThrow` is to (re)throw checked exceptions without compiler checking. If that is not the main goal of a Java developer, that Java developer will find no use for `sneakyThrow`. BTW your point about rethrowing Throwable being "possible in Java7" is as unclear as it was before.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: Since Java 7 you can catch a base class, i.e. even `Throwable`, and [re-throw the catched throwable without the need to declare that base class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow) (and without the need of a sneakyThrow). This was added because there was a high demand. And this **is** an essential difference: rethrowing does not need this hack anymore.

Comment: @holger Yes, that's a nice special case they handle better. Do you have any research reference which would back your claim that most usages of sneaky throw were with this case? All cases I am aware of are by people who agree that checked exceptions are a misfeature and have no remorse sidestepping the check. Rich Hickey and Martin Odersky are notable examples.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: I started my statement with “I think” and it came from my experience with lots of projects and the fact, that the Java core developer saw the high demand for that feature but not for other relaxation of the exception model. I don’t wanted to start a discussion; I thought my comment was easy to understand. However, it doesn’t come as a surprise that people “who agree that checked exceptions are a misfeature” are stepping over places where sneakyThrow seems to be needed all the time: they never try to do it differently. Our dev teams don’t have such a big need for sneakyThrow.

Comment: @holger Exactly,  that matches my observation: first and foremost the average Java dev would never want to use, or see used, the sneaky throw. Those which do end up using it are of the "rebellious" attitude towards checked exceptions.